# Android - Increase build number with Fastlane and Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, continuous-integration, fastlane

I'm trying to increase the build number of a particular variant in my android project with `Fastlane`.

I am using `Kotlin DSL` and Dev.kt for example is as follows.

```
object Dev: Variants {
     override val name = "DevVariant"
     override val versionCode = 7
     override val versionName = "1.2.0"
}
```

1- Here I want to increase the versionCode value by 1, how can I do that?
2- I also want to git commit&push this change after this operation.

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you solve your problem? i am facing the same.